# Can bank take 401(k) money when you foreclose

Tags: united-states, retirement, foreclosure

If you foreclose on a house, can the bank take money from your 401k or any type of retirement?

I heard they can take money out of your savings account or any bank account for that matter, but what about your retirement?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, 401(k) and IRA accounts are not at risk when you default on a mortgage, even in states that aren't non-recourse. In states where mortgages are non-recourse loans, the bank isn't allowed to go after you at all. They get the keys and whatever they recover from the house sale is it.

Answer (score 7):

Your 401K (and IRA) is a legally distinct entity from yourself. In fact, it is a "trust," and your Administrator is a "trustee," while you are both creator and benefactor.

This fact, and the 10% early withdrawal penalty, makes it immune from most judgments. The IRS can "levy" your 401K or IRA for back taxes, but must waive the 10% penalty (under the 1997 Tax Reform law). That gives them the power to do what most others can't.

A "tricky" banker may persuade you to take money out of your 401K to pay the bank. If you do, s/he has won. But s/he can't go after your 401k.